# What do I need to do to figure out bounds for integrating over triangle that does not touch both axes?

Tags: integration

What do I need to do to figure out bounds for integrating over triangle that does not touch both axes?

Such as the one with edges $(0,0), (1,1), (4,0)$.

If this was $(0,0), (0,1), (4,0)$ I'd view this simpler.

I'm thinking I'd need to subtract some rectangle or then find a way to describe the sides.

Comment: What? the latter three points are collinear, they don't form a triangle

Comment: In the second line, did you want to say $(0,0), (0,1), (4,0)$?

Answer (score 1):

Plotting or sketching the region helps. In the example you gave with points $(0,0), (1,1), (4,0)$, when we plot and based on the equation of lines, we realize that if we integrate along $y$ axis, we can do it as one integral.

For example if we were finding area, $A = \displaystyle \int_0^1 ((4-3y) - y) \, dy $

If we integrate along $x$ axis, we have to break it into two regions $(0 \leq x \leq 1)$ and $(1 \leq x \leq 4)$ or we have to find a change of variable.

[image]